# How to validate list of hostname on specific network type from extra variables and shorten assert code

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook which requires --extra-vars to be passed and would like to know if there is any way to shorten the assert code that validate the hostnames and specific network type from the --extra-vars values is within the variables.

sample playbook **pb.yml**

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    cz:
      prod_mgmt_network: "{{ ['prgprodsrv00']|product(range(4281,4395))|map('join')|list }}"
      prod_int_network: "{{ ['prgprodsrv00']|product(range(3481,4195))|map('join')|list }}"
      prod_dmz_network: "{{ ['prgprodsrv00']|product(range(5281,6395))|map('join')|list }}"
      prod_bkp_network: "{{ ['prgprodsrv00']|product(range(1281,2395))|map('join')|list }}"
      test_mgmt_network: "{{ ['prgtestsrv00']|product(range(8281,8321))|map('join')|list }}"
      test_int_network: "{{ ['prgtestsrv00']|product(range(8181,8221))|map('join')|list }}"
      test_dmz_network: "{{ ['prgtestsrv00']|product(range(9181,9221))|map('join')|list }}"
    us:
      prod_mgmt_network: "{{ ['phxprodsrv00']|product(range(4281,4395))|map('join')|list }}"
      prod_int_network: "{{ ['phxrodsrv00']|product(range(3481,4195))|map('join')|list }}"
      prod_dmz_network: "{{ ['phxprodsrv00']|product(range(5281,6395))|map('join')|list }}"
      prod_bkp_network: "{{ ['phxrodsrv00']|product(range(1281,2395))|map('join')|list }}"
      test_mgmt_network: "{{ ['phxtestsrv00']|product(range(8281,8321))|map('join')|list }}"
      test_int_network: "{{ ['phxtestsrv00']|product(range(8181,8221))|map('join')|list }}"
      test_dmz_network: "{{ ['phxtestsrv00']|product(range(9181,9221))|map('join')|list }}"
    my:
      prod_mgmt_network: "{{ ['kulprodsrv00']|product(range(4281,4395))|map('join')|list }}"
      prod_int_network: "{{ ['kulprodsrv00']|product(range(3481,4195))|map('join')|list }}"
      prod_dmz_network: "{{ ['kulprodsrv00']|product(range(5281,6395))|map('join')|list }}"
      prod_bkp_network: "{{ ['kulprodsrv00']|product(range(1281,2395))|map('join')|list }}"
      test_mgmt_network: "{{ ['kultestsrv00']|product(range(8281,8321))|map('join')|list }}"
      test_int_network: "{{ ['kultestsrv00']|product(range(8181,8221))|map('join')|list }}"
      test_dmz_network: "{{ ['kultestsrv00']|product(range(9181,9221))|map('join')|list }}"
  
  cz_prod_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', 'prgprodsrv') }}"
  cz_test_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', 'prgtestsrv') }}"
  us_prod_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', 'phxprodsrv') }}"
  us_test_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', 'phxtestsrv') }}"
  my_prod_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', 'kulxprodsrv') }}"
  my_test_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', 'kultestsrv') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: "Cluster: {{ clusterName }}, Network: prod_mgmt_network validation"
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: prod_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ prod_out }} out of {{ network }} network range."
      vars:
        prod_out: "{{ cz_prod_hosts|difference(cz.prod_mgmt_network) }}"
      when:
        - network == 'prod_mgmt_network'
        - clusterName | regex_search("^czprodcls")
   
    - name: "Cluster: {{ clusterName }}, Network: prod_int_network validation"
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: prod_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ prod_out }} out of {{ network }} network range."
      vars:
        prod_out: "{{ cz_prod_hosts|difference(cz.prod_int_network) }}"
      when:
        - network == 'prod_int_network'
        - clusterName | regex_search("^czprodcls")

    - name: "Cluster: {{ clusterName }}, Network: prod_dmz_network validation"
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: prod_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ prod_out }} out of {{ network }} network range."
      vars:
        prod_out: "{{ cz_prod_hosts|difference(cz.prod_dmz_network) }}"
      when:
        - network == 'prod_dmz_network'
        - clusterName | regex_search("^czprodcls")
    
    - name: "Cluster: {{ clusterName }}, Network: prod_bkp_network validation"
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: prod_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ prod_out }} out of {{ network }} network range."
      vars:
        prod_out: "{{ cz_prod_hosts|difference(cz.prod_bkp_network) }}"
      when:
        - network == 'prod_bkp_network'
        - clusterName | regex_search("^czprodcls")

    - name: "Cluster: {{ clusterName }}, Network: test_mgmt_network validation"
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: test_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ test_out }} out of {{ network }} network range."
      vars:
        test_out: "{{ cz_test_hosts|difference(cz.test_mgmt_network) }}"
      when:
        - network == 'test_mgmt_network'
        - clusterName | regex_search("^cztestcls")

    - name: "Cluster: {{ clusterName }}, Network: test_int_network validation"
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: test_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ test_out }} out of {{ network }} network range."
      vars:
        test_out: "{{ cz_test_hosts|difference(cz.test_int_network) }}"
      when:
        - network == 'test_int_network'
        - clusterName | regex_search("^cztestcls")
 
    - name: "Cluster: {{ clusterName }}, Network: test_dmz_network validation"
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: test_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ test_out }} out of {{ network }} network range."
      vars:
        test_out: "{{ cz_test_hosts|difference(cz.test_dmz_network) }}"
      when:
        - network == 'test_dmz_network'
        - clusterName | regex_search("^cztestcls")
  
---------continue with other region assert-----
```

those are repeating code and looks messy, it is possible for simplifying the codes?

Running playbook

```
ansible-playbook pb.yml -e '{"hostname": ["prgprodsrv004281", "prgprodsrv004382","prgprodsrv008281","prgprodsrv009599"], "clusterName": "czprodcls001", "network": "prod_mgmt_network"}'
```

hostname is not in the list will be failling

Comment: Why are the hostnames required to be entered via extra vars? It looks like creation of an inventory would solve the issue and probably eliminate the need in assertions at all.

Comment: 'kulxprodsrv' and `['phxrodsrv00']` seem to be typos. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the extra variables

```yaml
shell> cat extra.yml
hostname:
  - prgprodsrv004281
  - prgprodsrv004382
  - prgprodsrv008281
  - prgprodsrv009599
clusterName: czprodcls001
network: prod_mgmt_network
```

Create the dictionary *prefix* below. It will be used in *matcher* to select the list of hosts *sel_hosts* (instead of the declarations *_*_hosts).

```yaml
    prefix:
      cz: prg
      us: phx
      my: kul
```

Parse the variables *clusterName*

```yaml
    cls:
      country: "{{ clusterName[0:2] }}"
      team: "{{ clusterName[2:6] }}"
      no: "{{ clusterName[-3:] }}"
```

and *network*

```yaml
    net_arr: "{{ network|split('_') }}"
    net:
      team: "{{ net_arr.0 }}"
      type: "{{ net_arr.1 }}"
```

Declare the variable *matcher* and select the hosts

```yaml
  matcher: "{{ prefix[cls.country] }}{{ cls.team }}srv"
  sel_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', matcher) }}"
```

gives (provided with the extra variables)

```yaml
  matcher: prgprodsrv
  sel_hosts:
    - prgprodsrv004281
    - prgprodsrv004382
    - prgprodsrv008281
    - prgprodsrv009599
```

Use the attribute *country* and get the dictionary

```yaml
  sel_networks: "{{ lookup('vars', cls.country) }}"
```

Use it to select the network

```yaml
  sel_network: "{{ sel_networks[network] }}"
```

Then, the below assert

```yaml
    - name: "Cluster: {{ clusterName }}, Network: {{ network }} validation"
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: prod_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ prod_out }} out of {{ network }} network range."
      vars:
        prod_out: "{{ sel_hosts|difference(sel_network) }}"
```

will fail (as expected)

```yaml
TASK [Cluster: czprodcls001, Network: prod_mgmt_network validation] **************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: prod_out|length == 0
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: 'Hosts: [''prgprodsrv008281'', ''prgprodsrv009599''] out of prod_mgmt_network network range.'
```

---

**Example** of a complete playbook for testing.

(Put the dictionaries of the network's ranges into the file *networks.yml*)

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars_files:
    - networks.yml

  vars:

    prefix:
      cz: prg
      us: phx
      my: kul

    cls:
      country: "{{ clusterName[0:2] }}"
      team: "{{ clusterName[2:6] }}"
      no: "{{ clusterName[-3:] }}"

    net_arr: "{{ network|split('_') }}"
    net:
      team: "{{ net_arr.0 }}"
      type: "{{ net_arr.1 }}"

    matcher: "{{ prefix[cls.country] }}{{ cls.team }}srv"
    sel_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', matcher) }}"
    sel_networks: "{{ lookup('vars', cls.country) }}"
    sel_network: "{{ sel_networks[network] }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          cls: {{ cls }}
          net: {{ net }}
          matcher: {{ matcher }}
          sel_hosts: {{ sel_hosts }}
          {{ cls.country }}.{{ network }}: {{ sel_network }}

    - name: "Cluster: {{ clusterName }}, Network: {{ network }} validation"
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: prod_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ prod_out }} out of {{ network }} network range."
      vars:
        prod_out: "{{ sel_hosts|difference(sel_network) }}"
```

Run the play

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e @extra.yml
```

---

**Hint**: Simplify the data. Declare the ranges' intervals only

```yaml
shell> cat ranges.yml
prefix:
  cz: prg
  us: phx
  my: kul

cz:
  prod_mgmt_network: [4281, 4395]
  prod_int_network: [3481, 4195]
  prod_dmz_network: [5281, 6395]
  prod_bkp_network: [1281, 2395]
  test_mgmt_network: [8281, 8321]
  test_int_network: [8181, 8221]
  test_dmz_network: [9181, 9221]
us:
  prod_mgmt_network: [4281, 4395]
  prod_int_network: [3481, 4195]
  prod_dmz_network: [5281, 6395]
  prod_bkp_network: [1281, 2395]
  test_mgmt_network: [8281, 8321]
  test_int_network: [8181, 8221]
  test_dmz_network: [9181, 9221]
my:
  prod_mgmt_network: [4281, 4395]
  prod_int_network: [3481, 4195]
  prod_dmz_network: [5281, 6395]
  prod_bkp_network: [1281, 2395]
  test_mgmt_network: [8281, 8321]
  test_int_network: [8181, 8221]
  test_dmz_network: [9181, 9221]
```

Get the hosts' indices

```yaml
  sel_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', matcher)|
                          map('regex_replace', '^(\\D+)(\\d+)$', '\\2')|
                          map('int') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
sel_hosts: [4281, 4382, 8281, 9599]
```

and compare the limits

```yaml
  prod_out: "{{ sel_hosts|reject('ge', sel_network.0) +                                     
                sel_hosts|reject('le', sel_network.1) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  prod_out: [8281, 9599]
```

Then, the below assert

```yaml
    - name: "Cluster: {{ clusterName }}, Network: {{ network }} validation"
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: prod_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ prod_out }} out of {{ network }} network range."
```

will fail

```yaml
TASK [Cluster: czprodcls001, Network: prod_mgmt_network validation] **************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: prod_out|length == 0
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: 'Hosts: [8281, 9599] out of prod_mgmt_network network range.'
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars_files:
    - ranges.yml

  vars:

    cls:
      country: "{{ clusterName[0:2] }}"
      team: "{{ clusterName[2:6] }}"
      no: "{{ clusterName[-3:] }}"

    net_arr: "{{ network|split('_') }}"
    net:
      team: "{{ net_arr.0 }}"
      type: "{{ net_arr.1 }}"

    matcher: "{{ prefix[cls.country] }}{{ cls.team }}srv"
    sel_hosts: "{{ hostname|select('match', matcher)|
                            map('regex_replace', '^(\\D+)(\\d+)$', '\\2')|
                            map('int') }}"
    sel_networks: "{{ lookup('vars', cls.country) }}"
    sel_network: "{{ sel_networks[network] }}"
    prod_out: "{{ sel_hosts|reject('ge', sel_network.0) +
                  sel_hosts|reject('le', sel_network.1) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          cls: {{ cls }}
          net: {{ net }}
          matcher: {{ matcher }}
          sel_hosts: {{ sel_hosts }}
          {{ cls.country }}.{{ network }}: {{ sel_network }}
          prod_out: {{ prod_out }}

    - name: "Cluster: {{ clusterName }}, Network: {{ network }} validation"
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: prod_out|length == 0
        fail_msg: "Hosts: {{ prod_out }} out of {{ network }} network range."
```